# upgraded by the book 11.04 to 11.10. I want 11.04 back

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I grub xp, ubuntu and 2 puppys (one ram and one encrypted)
I upgraded to 11.10 and now I have ubuntu and xp only. I can probably fix this but it is a time consumer. It seems to me that 11.10 is MUCH slower on boot up and shut down than 11.04.
I should know better than to fix something that isn't broken. Is there a way to undo the upgrade to 11.10 without re-install?
Thanks not complaining -just thankful for the windows exscape you guys offer.

Comment: I suppose, if startup and shutdown times are your problem, you could try Unity 2D for a bit more speed.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading doesn't fix the booting options. The problem is that the GRUB settings have been changed by the install script. Can be fixed with this: [Other Linux Distros deleting Ubuntu from GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41952/other-linux-distros-deleting-ubuntu-from-grub)

You can use the Unity2D or Gnome classic shell [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)